# Как принимать платежи в TelegramBot на java с использованием SpringBoot?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Написан рабочий бот на `Java`, с использованием библиотеки `telegrambots-spring-boot-starter`.
Не могу разобраться как реализовать метод `sendInvoice`. Чтобы выставить счет нужно сформировать запрос как я понимаю, но каким способом?

```
    SendInvoice invoice = new SendInvoice();
    invoice.setProviderToken("provider_token");
    invoice.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
    invoice.setTitle("Платный пакет");
    invoice.setDescription("В платном пакете, сожержиться множество вопросов и заданий.");
    invoice.setCurrency("UAH");
    invoice.setPayload("{\"code\":\"UAH\",\"title\":\"Ukrainian}");
```

Этот объект служит для формирования Json, который нужно передать в запросе на сервер телеграма. И вот на этоп этапе не пойму, каким способом его передать и получить ответ. В документации о данном api ничего не нашел.